# Sent message to customers from whatsapp

Tags: whatsapp

i want to sent price rate every morning to my customers. So want to know is it possible with whats app business api / any other way. Im a java developer so i can create a project for this.

Answer (score 0):

Personal WhatsApp doesn't have an official feature to schedule messages. However, if you are using an Android smartphone, you can schedule messages on WhatsApp with the help of several third-party apps.— SKEDit — does it perfectly.
You can also use the business api, of you google whatsapp business api and look for the whatsapp link you'll find a lot of information that should point you in the right direction